# git add <filename> not working

Tags: windows, git

When i am typing

```
git add *.c
```

the error shown is

```
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Application Data/': 
Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/ElevatedDiagnostics/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/History/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/Content.IE5/': Permission d                                                                                                          enied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/Low/Content.IE5/': Permissi                                                                                                          on denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/': Permissio                                                                                                          n denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Temporary Internet Files/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Application Data/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Cookies/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Documents/My Music/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Documents/My Pictures/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Documents/My Videos/': Permission denied
      0 [sig] bash 22680! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process (pid 23616)
warning: could not open directory 'Local Settings/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'My Documents/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'NetHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'PrintHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Recent/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'SendTo/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Start Menu/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Templates/': Permission denied
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .atom/packages/script/examples/colored_diagnostics.c.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .atom/packages/script/examples/hello.c.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .atom/recovery/stringdel-c5a98d.c.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Lib/site-packages/nump                                                                                                          y/distutils/mingw/gfortran_vs2003_hack.c.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Lib/site-packages/nump                                                                                                          y/f2py/src/fortranobject.c.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Lib/site-packages/nump                                                                                                          y/f2py/tests/src/array_from_pyobj/wrapmodule.c.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in AppData/Local/atom/app-1.27.0/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm                                                                                                          /node_modules/request/node_modules/node-uuid/benchmark/benchmark-native.c.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in AppData/Local/atom/app-1.27.1/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm                                                                                                          /node_modules/request/node_modules/node-uuid/benchmark/benchmark-native.c.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in AppData/Local/atom/app-1.27.2/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm                                                                                                          /node_modules/request/node_modules/node-uuid/benchmark/benchmark-native.c.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
1241365 [sig] bash 22680! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process (pid 23616)
2219951 [sig] bash 22680! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process (pid 23616)
2611925 [sig] bash 22680! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process (pid 23616)
2758249 [sig] bash 22680! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process (pid 23616)
2990144 [sig] bash 22680! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process (pid 23616)
3176253 [sig] bash 22680! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process (pid 23616)
3360807 [sig] bash 22680! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process (pid 23616)
3523597 [sig] bash 22680! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process (pid 23616)
3746325 [sig] bash 22680! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process (pid 23616)
3964192 [sig] bash 22680! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process (pid 23616)
4150814 [sig] bash 22680! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process (pid 23616)
4335693 [sig] bash 22680! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process (pid 23616)
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Desktop/exploringBB-master/chp03/HelloWorldSleep.c.
....
```

Please help me. I do not know what to do just to add a file. My repository folder has some files that do not have permission. How do I change these permissions or should I change my repository folder>
I'm currently working under windows.

Comment: Why does your repository work tree contain folders to which you don't have permission?  The best path to a solution depends on that answer.

Comment: permit to its path with: `sudo chmod -R 750 .`

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I changed the folder where it did not require permissions. It worked. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to perform git operations inside your user directory.
`C:\Users\{user-name}`

Please make sure your git bash or cmd points to correct folder.

I had the same issue and by navigating to correct folder it worked fine for me

As a suggestion use `cd foldername` then again `cd foldername` to navigate

Answer (score 1):

You just need to delete log files.

Use the command

```sh
rm -rf .git
```

It will solve your problem. Before entering this command remember one thing that it will clear all your log files and delete .git folder.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I solved this error by running the following commands:

```sh
git init
git add -A
git Commit -a -m "your message"
```

Comment: The issue was due to permission.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure u are in the correct path(folder)
then use :

```
git init
git status
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your directory where the actual files are located then list them  (ls -l). You will find your file there.  once you done this your command will work fine `git add <filename>`.

What I did is:

```
sarat@DESKTOP-9BPO08D MINGW64 /d
$ cd files1

sarat@DESKTOP-9BPO08D MINGW64 /d/files1
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/files1/.git/

sarat@DESKTOP-9BPO08D MINGW64 /d/files1 (master)
$ ls -l
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarat 197609 396 May 25 21:15 Camera_Follow.cs

sarat@DESKTOP-9BPO08D MINGW64 /d/files1 (master)
$ git add Camera_Follow.cs

sarat@DESKTOP-9BPO08D MINGW64 /d/files1 (master)
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   Camera_Follow.cs
```

Comment: Great, but please use the `Code Sample` format button (`{}`) for code pasting. This makes your answer more readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you didn't initialised git on you folder,

Start by:

```
git init 
git status
git add -A
```

it will work